# Show that $K_{r, s}$ is planar if and only if $\min$ {r, s} ≤ 2.

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, planar-graphs, bipartite-graphs

So I've done some draws and this is true, but How can I argument to prove that, by the maximum number of edges in $K$ ?

Or by $d(v)$

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This basically boils down to a special case of Kuratowski's theorem. In the special case of bipartite graphs, this will say that your graph will be planar if and only if it does not contain $K_{3, 3}$ as a minor. First, you would show that $K_{3, 3}$ is not planar (and hence neither is any bipartite graph containing $K_{3, 3}$ as a minor), and then show that $K_{r, 2}$ is in fact planar for any $r$ (you can just explicitly draw $K_{r, 2}$ as a plane graph in this case to demonstrate planarity).

Comment: I'm still a little confused, only by showing that I'm done woth the proof?

Comment: So I don't have to prove p <-- q ?

Comment: I'm not sure which statement you're referring to, but assuming you mean $\text{min}\{r, s\}\leq 2$ implies $K_{r, s}$ is planar, this is proven when you show that $K_{r, 2}$ is planar (we can just assume it is $s$ which is the minimum, and is $\leq 2$, without loss of generality). Technically you also need to consider the possibility of $s = 1$ too, but this is trivial to check that $K_{r, s}$ is planar in this case. It is still pretty simple when $s = 2$ as well.

Comment: Ohh, thanks, I think I have the idea using the fact that for any planar graph $|E|$ ≤ $3|V| - 6$

Comment: Sure thing. I'm still not sure if we are referring to the same direction of implication based on your last comment, because the edge bound that you mention is a $\textbf{necessary}$ condition, but it is not sufficient. In other words, if that bound is violated, then you can certainly infer that the graph is not planar, but OTOH, just because a graph satisfies that bound does not automatically make it planar. So the edge bound is useful for proving the converse implication - not the one which my previous comment addressed. For that implication, you can explicitly show the graph is planar.

Comment: The direction you asumed I was refering is correct :)

Comment: Thanks again! :)

Comment: Ok great, you're welcome!